# Get links from a certain div using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following HTML page. I want to get all the links inside a specific div. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="rec_view">
    <a href='www.xyz.com/firstlink.html'>
        <img src='imga.png'>
    </a>
    <a href='www.xyz.com/seclink.html'>
        <img src='imgb.png'>
    </a>
    <a href='www.xyz.com/thrdlink.html'>
        <img src='imgc.png'>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to get all the links that are present on the `rec_view` div. So those links that I want are,

```
www.xyz.com/firstlink.html
www.xyz.com/seclink.html
www.xyz.com/thrdlink.html
```

Here is the Python code which I tried with

```
from selenium import webdriver;
webpage = r"https://www.testurl.com/page/123/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(webpage)
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='rec_view']>a")
link = element.get_attribute("href")
print(link)
```

How can I get those links using selenium on Python?

Comment: are you sure your code does not work ? and if not , please tell us what you get when you run it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared to get the list of all the links that are present on the `rec_view` div you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.testurl.com/page/123/')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.rec_view a")
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

**Note** : As you need to collect all the *href* attributes from the *div* tag so instead of `find_element_*` you need to use `find_elements_*`. Additionally, `>` refers to immediate `<a>` child node where as you need to traverse all the `<a>` child nodes so the desired `css_selector` will be **`div.rec_view a`**

Comment: I hava a similar problem. I want to extract all href that correspond to "tif" from [link](http://www.lanot.unam.mx/goes.php) and save it into a list. I tried with ```by_partial_linked_text("goes-16.rgb.tif")``` and ```by_xpath()``` but in both the list is empty. Using ```by_css_selector("marco_goes.div.div.modal-body.div.div.div.ol.li a")```